# Остановить выполнение setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, рекурсия, settimeout

Функция анимации реализована на setTimeout() через рекурсию.
Как можно прервать ее выполнение из другой функции?

```
animate: function(itm, prop, unit, fromVal, toVal, time, callback){

    slider.sett.progress = true;
    var fps = .06;
    var frame = 0;
    var direction = fromVal < toVal ? true : false;
    var distance = direction ? (toVal - fromVal) : (fromVal - toVal);
    var delta = distance / time / fps;

    var handle = setTimeout(function run() {
        frame++;
        var step = delta * frame;
        var value = direction ? (fromVal + step) : (fromVal - step) ;
        itm.style[prop] = value + unit;
        if (direction && value < toVal || !direction && value > toVal) { 
            setTimeout(run, 1 / fps);
        } else {
            itm.style[prop] = value + unit;
            slider.sett.progress = false;
            callback ? callback() : false;
        }
    });
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
animate: function(itm, prop, unit, fromVal, toVal, time, callback){
  ...
  var timeoutHolder = {};
  timeoutHolder.handle = setTimeout(function run() {
    ... 
    if (direction && value < toVal || !direction && value > toVal) { 
      timeoutHolder.handle = setTimeout(run, 1 / fps);
    } else {
      ...
    }
  });
  return timeoutHolder;
},

var timeout = a.animate(...);
clearTimeout(timeout.handle);
```

Обратите внимание на присвоение `timeoutHolder.handle` при повторных вызовах `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 3):

Очистить можно с помощью:

```
clearTimeout(handle);
```

**UPD**

```
var handle;
var obj = {

    animate: function(itm, prop, unit, fromVal, toVal, time, callback){

        slider.sett.progress = true;
        var fps = .06;
        var frame = 0;
        var direction = fromVal < toVal ? true : false;
        var distance = direction ? (toVal - fromVal) : (fromVal - toVal);
        var delta = distance / time / fps;

        handle = setTimeout(function run() {
            frame++;
            var step = delta * frame;
            var value = direction ? (fromVal + step) : (fromVal - step) ;
            itm.style[prop] = value + unit;
            if (direction && value < toVal || !direction && value > toVal) { 
                setTimeout(run, 1 / fps);
            } else {
                itm.style[prop] = value + unit;
                slider.sett.progress = false;
                callback ? callback() : false;
            }
        });
    }

}
if( handle ) clearTimeout(handle);
```

> Обратите внимание! Таймер внутри объявлен без var!

Comment: если я делаю это из другой функции то получаю 
Uncaught ReferenceError: handle is not defined

Comment: ))) В начале скрипта объявите `var handle`, а в самой функции используйте без `var`.

Comment: @Joe ну так передай аргументом что чистить

Comment: @Joe, добавил под `upd`, про что писал чуть выше.